# Functional testing clickAndWait not working

Tags: php, selenium, yii, phpunit, selenium-webdriver

I am writing web application in yii with the phpunit selenum testing here is my test case for the login form

```
public function testHasLoginForm()
    {
        $this->open('site/login');
        $this->assertTextPresent('Login');

        $this->assertElementPresent('name=LoginForm[username]');
        $this->assertElementPresent('name=LoginForm[password]');

        $this->assertTextPresent('Remember me next time');  
        $this->assertTextPresent('Reset Password?');

        $this->assertElementPresent('name=Login');

        $this->type('name=LoginForm[username]','pradeep@techanveshan.com');
        $this->type('name=LoginForm[password]','password');

        $this->clickAndWait("//input[@value='Login']"); //this line cause the error

    }
```

Everything works find unless i put this command 
**$this->clickAndWait("//input[@value='Login']");**

This line gives me error something like this :

```
Invalid response while accessing the Selenium Server at "http://localhost:4444/s
elenium-server/driver/:" ERROR: Command execution failure. Please search the use
r group at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/selenium-users for error deta
ils from the log window.  The error message is: Value does not implement interfa
ce Event.
```

Does anyone has idea why is this happening ?

Comment: Try click by name: 
    $this->clickAndWait('//input[name="LoginForm[username]"]');

Answer (score 5):

```
clickAndWait() is not available in RC or webdriver.
```

instead, you can use

```
$this->click("//input[@value='Login']");
$this->waitforpagetoload("30000");
```